# Filtering results in Trending

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

One of the results I get when using the [Trending](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/insights_trending) endpoint has a `"mediaType": "application/octet-stream"`, which I figured out is a folder. Is it possible to get everything else except folders?

I tried:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/insights/trending?$filter=ResourceVisualization/MediaType ne 'application/octet-stream'
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the end of next week, we will add a new property under the ResourceVisualization called "Type", that for this case will have the value "Folder". You can use that to filter out folders.

The documentation will also be updated to reflect this change. Stay tuned. :)

Comment: I have tried the "Folder" media type, however, I never get any result, just "value":"[]"